# Melting a spherical ball with density

Tags: geometry

Six spherical copper balls of radius 6 centimeters fit snugly, one on top of the other, inside a cylindrical can. The copper balls are melted and poured into the can. How high, in centimeters, will the molten copper rise? Assume that the density of solid copper is 8.96 g/mL and the density of liquid copper is 8.02 g/mL.

NOTE: 1 cu. cm. = 1 mL.

I got the volume of the copper balls and the volume of the cylinder, I don't know the next step to find the height.

Comment: The volume of the cylindre doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You say you know the volume of the cylinder. I assume that you computed it using some height (probably 72cm) for the cylinder. However, if you can do that computation you can probably also compute the volume of a cylinder with any given different height. And if you can do that, I have no doubt that you can even compute the volume of a cylinder with an 'abstract' height $h$.

Once you can do that, the question 'for which $h$ is the volume of a cylinder with height $h$ (and radius equal to that of the original cylinder) equal to the volume of the molten balls?' is not that hard.

And the answer to that question is the answer to the question of how high the copper will rise.

Answer (score 0):

The mass of copper is

$$m=6d_s\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}.$$

When melted, the volume is

$$v=\frac m{d_m}=6\frac{d_s}{d_m}\frac{4\pi r^3}{3},$$

hence the height

$$h=\frac v{\pi r^2}=8\frac{d_s}{d_m}r.$$